# Continuous transformation of a connected set

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $1\leq m\leq n$ and $\mathcal{O}$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathcal{O},\mathbb{R}^m)$, such that the differential of $f$ at any $x\in\mathcal{O}$ is surjective.

**Question:** For $(y_n)$ a sequence of elements of $\mathbb{R}^m$ converging to a certain $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$, if the level lines $f^{-1}\big(\{y_n\}\big)$ are connected sets, is the set $f^{-1}\big(\{y\}\big)$ connected?

Comment: This is more like an exercise than a research level question.

Comment: Have you ever sat on a tire swing on a sunny day? Have you looked down at the ground under you to see your shadow?

Comment: @BenMcKay: I happen to think of myself more as a closed set, and I am not sure whether your hint is as effective. (To OP: Ben McKay is suggesting that you think about the case where m = 1, n = 2, and $f$ is a projection map.)

Comment: @WillieWong: $m=2, n=3$

Comment: @WillieWong, thank you for your hint, but I do not find the counter-example. Would it still work if $\mathcal{O}$ is assumed to be connected?

Comment: A tire is connected, and path connected. You could even slice it a little to get a simply connected example. Try math.stackexchange for this problem.

Comment: @BenMcKay: I admit that when I saw "tire swing" I thought https://images.app.goo.gl/s8W7bvBZEBw8jJUg8 and not https://images.app.goo.gl/uWhD8bdiu9jFNcke7 ; now your comment makes a bit more sense to me with the latter in mind.

Comment: @WillieWong: thanks for pointing that out; I forgot about the two different arrangements of tire swings. I should get to the park more often.

Comment: Hello, I adapted the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218364/propagation-of-connectivity-for-level-lines-of-a-submersion Thank you.